# Generate waveform from stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, naudio

I need to generate a waveform based on multiple audio files (.wav/.mp3). I'm currently using NAudio but I'm having some issues with it. I can't use the path of the file(s) because I'm not allowed to upload the files to the server and most browsers block the path (security reasons), so my approach was to use a stream or memorystream to it.  I've found this [project](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio.WaveFormRenderer) that does something very similar but I'm not able to get it to work without a direct path to the file(s). 
This is my code from retriving the file from the user

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadAudioFile()
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            List<MusicViewModel> list = new List<MusicViewModel>();
            var supportedFileTypes = new[] { "audio/mp3", "audio/wav" };
            foreach (string file in Request.Files)
            {
                var _file = Request.Files[file];
                if (_file != null)
                {
                    var contentType = _file.ContentType.ToLower();
                    if (supportedFileTypes.Contains(contentType))
                    {

                        var s = _file.InputStream;                           

                        var name = _file.FileName;
                        var song = new MusicViewModel();
                        System.Drawing.Image img;
                        if (contentType.Equals("audio/mp3"))
                        {
                            song = _musicRepo.GetMetaDataFromMp3File(s, name);
                            img = _musicRepo.GenerateWaveForm(s);
                        }
                        else if (contentType.Equals("audio/wav"))
                        {
                            song = _musicRepo.GetMetaDataFromWavFile(s, name);
                            img = _musicRepo.GenerateWaveForm(s);
                        }
                        if (song != null)
                        {
                            list.Add(song);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Json(new { isSuccess = false, errorMsg = "We only allow audio files of .mp3 or .wav format. You have attempted to upload a file with " + contentType + "." });
                    }
                }
            }
            return Json(new { isSuccess = true, musicList = list });
        }

        return Json(new { isSuccess = false });
    }
```

Then GenerateWaveForm in my music repository

```
public Image GenerateWaveForm(Stream stream)
    {
        Image img = null;
        WaveFormRenderer wr = new WaveFormRenderer();
        try
        {
            img = wr.Render(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
        return img;
    }
```

I'm following the approach of this [class](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio.WaveFormRenderer/blob/master/WaveFormRendererLib/WaveFormRenderer.cs) but I receive an error of "Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header". This is my class that creates the exception

```
public Image Render(Stream stream)
    {
        int destBytesPerSample = 0;
        long samples;
        WaveStream readerStream = new WaveFileReader(stream);

        if (readerStream.WaveFormat.Encoding != WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm && readerStream.WaveFormat.Encoding != WaveFormatEncoding.IeeeFloat)
        {
            readerStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(readerStream);
            readerStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(readerStream);
            var sourceBytesPerSample = (readerStream.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8) * readerStream.WaveFormat.Channels;
            SampleChannel sampleChannel = new SampleChannel(readerStream, false);

            destBytesPerSample = 4 * sampleChannel.WaveFormat.Channels;
            samples = destBytesPerSample * (readerStream.Length / sourceBytesPerSample);
            var peakProvider = getPeakProvider();

            WaveFormRendererSettings settings = GetRendererSettings();
            var samplesPerPixel = (int)(samples / settings.Width);
            var stepSize = settings.PixelsPerPeak + settings.SpacerPixels;
            //peakProvider.Init(reader, samplesPerPixel * stepSize);
            return Render(peakProvider, settings);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The exception occurs when I try to create the object readerStream in line 3 in method Render

Comment: Does that happen on a mp3 or wav file? Mp3 files are not based on RIFF so make sure to call new Mp3FileReader when processing these files.